# Cantor-Bernstein with "weakly injective" functions

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let us call a map $f: X \to Y$ between non-empty sets a "weak injection" if $f^{-1}(\{y\})\subseteq X$ is finite for every $y \in Y$.

Recall that the [(Schroeder-)Cantor-Bernstein-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) (sometimes abbreviated by (CB)) states that if there are injections between two sets $X, Y$, then there is also a bijection between $X$ and $Y$. (CB) is a theorem of ${\sf (ZF)}$.

Consider the following statement:

> (wiCB) If $X, Y$ are infinite sets such that there are weak injections between $X$ and $Y$, then there is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

Obviously, (wiCB) implies (CB). Can (wiCB) also be proved in ${\sf (ZF)}$?

Comment: I have also heard "finite-to-one" and, more cutely, "finjective" used for weakly injective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is not provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is a sequence of disjoint two-element sets whose union is not countable, i.e. $\vert A_i\vert=2$ but there is no bijection between $A:=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

WLOG, $A\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$. Now let $B_i=A_i\sqcup\{i\}$ and let $B=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i$. We have obvious weak injections $B\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$, the former sending $x\in B_i$ to $i$ and the latter sending $i$ to $i$, but $B$ is not countable.

Comment: And more generally (wiCB) implies that the union of $\aleph_\alpha$ finite sets has cardinality at most $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: Hmm, this raises an interesting separate question of if wiCB is equivalent to Choice. My guess is that it is weaker.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Probably decently weaker. E.g. if every set can be linearly ordered and $|X\times\omega|=|X|$ for all infinite $X$ then we get wiCB. That sounds doable in the "$\omega_1$ Cohen model", but I'm not certain.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith: It's not clear to me which is the "$\omega_1$ Cohen model". Note that $|X\times\omega|=|X|$ if and only if $|X|=|X|+|X|$, so we really just need that every set is linearly orderable along with that. Luckily, Sageev's model (which is really the only model we really know about where $|X|+|X|=|X|$ holds for every infinite set $X$ and choice fails) satisfies that every set can be linearly ordered. (This is Lemma 9.30 in his massive paper.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\operatorname{Add}(\omega_1,\omega_1)$, countable-support permutations of $\omega_1$, etc. My naive hope is (was?) that $\mathsf{SVC}(A)$ for a linearly orderable $A$ with $\aleph(A)>\aleph_0$ would be enough.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith: Unfortunately, this isn't true. At least your hopes part, for example in most Solovay model-type results, we have that $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ cannot be linearly ordered, but $\sf SVC(\Bbb R)$ holds, since $V=L(\Bbb R)$. What you need is an injective seed which is linearly ordered. That's not so easy to find, and outright impossible in many cases.

Comment: @CalliopeRyan-Smith: In the case of the model you describe, note that there is (1) no reason to expect that the set $A$ of Cohen reals satisfies $|A|+|A|=|A|$, and (2) some reals will not have a canonical support where we can inject every set into $A$ or even into $[A]^\omega$, and even worse, some might not even have a canonical enumeration for their support, and there is no definable order on $[A]^\omega$ anyway.